# How to get around the limitation of the Oracle MERGE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to update two more variables, i.e., 'earliest_id only when earliest_timestamp is updated' and 'latest_id only when latest_timestamp is updated'. Is there any way to do this in the MERGE below. Else, if you guys have alternate solutions for the read modify write problem below, please share it with me

```
BEGIN
MERGE INTO mytable
USING dual ON (id1 = ? AND ...)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (...) VALUES (...)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET earliest_timestamp = least(lEarliest, earliest_timestamp), 
    latest_timestamp   = greatest(lLatest, latest_timestamp) 
    where earliest_timestamp > lEarliest or latest_timestamp < lLatest;
END;
/
```

Comment: Are you inserting values if not found or you only want to update ?

Comment: You are more likely to get a meaningful response if you provide DDL for the tables, DML to create data to demonstrate the issue, minimum code to demonstrate the issue, and the error message.

Comment: What limitation of `merge` do you mean? By 'variables', do you mean 'columns'? What are `lEarliest` and `lLatest`? By the way, the enclosing `begin ... end;` keywords don't add any functionality, apart from changing the completion message from *n rows merged* to *PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of using `dual` table also since you are updating
one table, you can use `update` statement rather than `merge`.

```
update mytable
set earliest_timestamp = least(lEarliest, earliest_timestamp), 
    latest_timestamp   = greatest(lLatest, latest_timestamp) 
    where earliest_timestamp > lEarliest or latest_timestamp < lLatest;
```